# ENVÍO DE DATOS A OTRA HOJA

Tags: excel

Muy buenas, he realizado un formulario en una hoja de excel donde hay que ir ingresando datos cada vez que se realiza un movimiento de vino en una bodega. 
 Lo que pretendo conseguir, aunque creo que es poco probable es que cada vez que yo pulse una celda(llamamos "Enviar", todos los datos de cada celda se trasladen a otra hoja a posiciones específicas dentro de ésta. Eso es facil (salvo por lo de tener un boton-celda de "enviar".
Lo complicado para mi, y no soy capaz por más tiempo y tutoriales que vea, es conseguir que este traspaso de datos se mantenga cuando yo borre los datos ingresados del formulario para introduciir otros y, que una vez vuelva a ingresar nuevos datos y vuelva a darle a "enviar", estos nuevos datos del formulario también se pasen a la otra hoja, pero en la fila siguiente a la anteriormente rellenada con los datos previos. Y quiero que este trabajo sea para cuantas lineas de ingreso desee, es decir, sin tener limitaciones ya que quiero conseguir llevar una contabilidad con mucho movimientos de vino.
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Qué tienes hecho hasta ahora?
Enseña tú código para que veamos cómo de avanzado lo tienes.

Comment: Lo que dices se puede hacer perfectamente con macros en VBA. Tendrás que diseñar un código para que lleve los datos de un sitio a otro. Respecto a lo del botón, busca en Google "pestaña programador en Excel" y ahí tienes un menú para meter el botón y asignarle la macro.